# Spark2 session for Cassandra , sql queries

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

In Spark-2.0 what is the best way to create a Spark session. Because in both  Spark-2.0 and Cassandra- the APIs have been reworked, essentially deprecating the SqlContext (and also CassandraSqlContext). So for executing SQL- either I create a Cassandra Session `(com.datastax.driver.core.Session) and use execute( " ")`. Or I have to create a `SparkSession (org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) and execute sql(String sqlText)` method.

I don't know the SQL limitations of either - can someone explain.

Also if I have to create the SparkSession - how do I do it- couldn't find any suitable example. With APIs getting reworked the old examples don't work. 
I was going thru this code sample- [DataFrames](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)- not clear what sql context is being used here (is that the right approach going forward.)
(For some reason deprecated APIs are not even compiling - need to check my eclipse settings)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need Cassandra Session for create/drop keyspace and table from Cassandra DB. In Spark application, in order to create Cassandra Session you need to pass SparkConf to CassandraConnector. In Spark 2.0 you can do it like below.

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("SparkCassandraApp")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
              .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
              .master("local[2]")
              .getOrCreate();

CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(spark.sparkContext().conf());
Session session = connector.openSession();
session.execute("CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable(id UUID PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, email TEXT)");
```

If you have existing Dataframe then you can create table in Cassandra using `DataFrameFunctions.createCassandraTable(Df)` as well. See api details [here](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.0.0/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.DataFrameFunctions).

You can read data from Cassandra DB using api provided by spark-cassandra-connector like below.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                {
                    put("keyspace", "mykeyspace");
                    put("table", "mytable");
                }
            }).load();

dataset.show();
```

You can use SparkSession.sql() method to run query on temporary table created on Dataframe returned by spark cassandra connector like below.

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("usertable");
Dataset<Row> dataset1 = spark.sql("select * from usertable where username = 'Mat'");
dataset1.show();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Are there any limitations pros/cons of running queries using Spark or Cassandra - any sql limitations. Understand to create keyspace/table will have to use cassandra.

Comment: Also SparkSession.sql() - can I run queries only against temp tables and not against Cassandra tables?. The Spark documentation does not state that. The docs state" The dialect that is used for SQL parsing can be configured with 'spark.sql.dialect' . For a SQLContext, the only dialect available is “sql” which uses a simple SQL parser provided by Spark SQL. In a HiveContext, the default is “hiveql”, though “sql” is also available. Since the HiveQL parser is much more complete, this is recommended for most use cases."

Comment: No SparkSession.sql is not limited to temporary table. You can connect to different databases using Spark JDBC. With SparkCassandraConnector it  is much easy to work with Cassandra DB.

Comment: I did all this, created sparks session, Cassandra session - created keyspace and table using Cassandra session - inserted data into table. I can see everything in the cqlsh shell. But when I run a simple spark query : `Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparks.sql("SELECT * FROM java_api.products");` **errors:**  `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `java_api`.`products``

Comment: But if do `sparks.read().format *( ).options (HashMap ()`  - it works.

Comment: @abaghel can you please help me with this....writing to cassandra   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535223/how-to-save-oracle-dataframe-into-cassandra