# Spark Cassandra Connector: Implement SCD Type 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am newbie for the Cassandra and I want to implement **SCD Type-1** in Cassandra DB.
This SCD Type1 job will be executed from the Spark.
The data will be stored as time series partitioned data. viz: Year/month/Day

**Example**: I have records for the last 300 days and my new records may have the new records as well as the updated records.
I want to compare the updated records for the last 100 days and if the records are new then it should perform the insert operation else update.

I am not getting any clue to perform this operation hence not sharing any CQL :(

Sample table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE crossfit_gyms_by_city_New (  
 country_code text,  
 state_province text,  
 city text,  
 gym_name text,  
 PRIMARY KEY ((country_code, state_province), gym_name)  
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (gym_name ASC );
```

My Sample Spark Code:

```
object SparkUpdateCassandra {
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      .appName("Spark Cassandra Connector Example")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    //Read Cassandra data using DataFrame
    val FirstDF = Seq(("India", "WB", "Kolkata", "Cult Fit"),("India", "KA", "Bengaluru", "Cult Fit")).toDF("country_code", "state_province","city","gym_name")
    FirstDF.show(10)
    FirstDF.write
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
          .mode("append")
          .option("confirm.truncate", "true")
          .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
          .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .option("keyspace", "emc_test")
          .option("table", "crossfit_gyms_by_city_new")
          .save()
    val loaddf1 = spark.read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .options(Map( "table" -> "crossfit_gyms_by_city_new", "keyspace" -> "emc_test"))
      .load()
    loaddf1.show(10)

//    spark.implicits.wait(5000)

    val SecondDF = Seq(("India", "WB", "Siliguri", "CultFit"),("India", "KA", "Bengaluru", "CultFit")).toDF("country_code", "state_province","city","gym_name")
    SecondDF.show(10)

    SecondDF.write
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .mode("append")
      .option("confirm.truncate", "true")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .option("keyspace", "emc_test")
      .option("table", "crossfit_gyms_by_city_new")
      .save()

    val loaddf2 = spark.read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
      .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .options(Map( "table" -> "crossfit_gyms_by_city_new", "keyspace" -> "emc_test"))
      .load()
    loaddf2.show(10)


  }
}
```

Note: I am using Scala for the Spark framework.

Comment: you don't need `.option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")` on every read if you set it when creating SparkSession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cassandra everything is upsert - if row doesn't exist it will be inserted, if it exists, then it will be updated, so you just need to get your data into RDD or DataFrame and use corresponding function of Spark Cassandra Connector:

[saveToCassandra for RDD API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#saving-a-collection-of-tuples):

```scala
rdd.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
```

Or just [`write` inDataFrame API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md):

```scala
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "table_name", "keyspace" -> "keyspace_name"))
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

Comment: I execute the code without the adding any 'mode' then it is throwing the exception: '
SaveMode is set to ErrorIfExists and Table
emc_test.crossfit_gyms_by_city already exists and contains data.
Perhaps you meant to set the DataFrame write mode to Append?
Example: df.write.format.options.mode(SaveMode.Append).save()'

Comment: for more clarity I have added the Spark code and updated the query to make question more easy to understand.

Comment: just use `SaveMode.Append` - it will handle both existing & new data

Comment: `mode(SaveMode.Append)` is not working, for this I am getting an exception which is asking me to use mode("append") only. And all the 4 rows are getting inserted though logically it should be 3 only. My second dataframe has 1 new row and one updated row. Did I made any mistake at the time of table creation?

Comment: As I said, there is no separation between insert & update in Cassandra. In your code I see 2 DFs, with 4 values. You save both DFs, so you get all 4 records there.

Comment: country_code, state_province are my primary Keys and if DB has the records with this primary keys then it should check rest of the columns 
if the dataframe values are new then it should replace the existing value with the new column values. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your primary key consists of 3 columns, not 2. Country and state are partition keys... if you need it to be primary key, then remove gym name

Comment: your table's Primary Key is incorrect - it should be `((country_code), state_province)` or `((country_code, state_province))` - you need to remove `gym_name`

Comment: One last question- If I have billions of records then would this approach `insert/update` would be efficient??

Comment: The more effective would be just remove duplicate records in the spark, for example, by groupByKey, etc. In this case you will write only unique values. From Cassandra standpoint, it doesn't see difference between insert & update.

Comment: Can I create a partitioned table without including the column names in `PRIMARY KEY` and `CLUSTERING ORDER BY`?? can you please share the example.

Comment: Short answer - no. Column name(s) are required for at least partition key that defines location of data on servers, and full primary key defines uniquiness of the data. I recommend to take DS201 & DS220 courses on https://academy.datastax.com/

Comment: I mean I want to partition the data but the partitioned column name should not be part of the `Compound key`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this there are some facts that will help you navigate the code examples you will run into

In previous Spark 1 code we would use
1 A SparkContext [see docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html)
2 To connect to Cassandra  use a CassandraSQLContext constructed with the SparkContext

For Spark 2 this has mostly changed
Create a  Spark Session and a [CassandraConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023957/spark2-session-for-cassandra-sql-queries)[1]

You would then run your native SQL with the session as shown in [1]

Once you have this set up and working you can just execute the appropriate sql for SCD Type 1 operations, [good examples](http://yuzongbao.com/2019/08/05/scd-implementation-with-databricks-delta/) of the sql involved can be found.

Comment: suggest solution quite vague.

Comment: I did not see your code updates before and I focused on " not sharing any CQL"